# Angular 9 throw CORS error on loading page

Tags: oauth-2.0, cors, azure-ad-b2c, angular9, .net-core-3.1

I am working on Angular 9 application with .NET CORE Web API 3.1 application. I configure Angular client App to authenticate using Auth 2.0 Azure B2C and using angular-oauth2-oidc library in Angular. I am getting CORS Policy error soon I call http://localhost:4200

[image]

I can successfully call AD B2C via Postman and get token

When click on Login button, I get following error

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADB2C90083: The request is missing required parameter: grant_type.\r\nCorrelation ID: xxxxxf7b-f507-48bc-884f-41xxxxxxxxxx\r\nTimestamp: 2020-05-08 09:21:41Z\r\n"}
```

[image]

### component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { JwksValidationHandler } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc-jwks';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'Angular9B2CAuthApp';

constructor(private oauthService:OAuthService){
  this.configureSingleSignOn();
}

configureSingleSignOn(){
  this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
  this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
  this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
}

login(){
  this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
}

logout(){
  this.oauthService.logOut();
}
}
```

### Auth.config

[image]

### error after updating login url

[image]

Comment: The response is a 400 Bad Request error. That’s what the https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReFkG.png screenshot shows. That 400 error is the actual problem you need to fix, not CORS.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the [token endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#get-a-token) (which does not support CORS and is not intented for SPA/Implicit Flow/GET calls thus the 400 status code) into your config loginUrl property. You have to set it to your user flow or policy [authorize endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-authentication-requests) like this:

```
{
  "loginUrl":"https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
}
```

Comment: Many thanks I have manage to make it work once... I am still getting error loading discovery document, CORS and HttpErrorResponse error. I have uploaded full screenshot above at bottom of description

Comment: I think this library makes OPTIONS call to discovery endpoint, which we don’t support. We only support GET to discovery endpoint. Check the network trace in the browser to see the HTTP method being used&blocked.